# Selecting items from combined stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures, report

I had two separate stored procedures each with their own column description and info. Now that i combined them both information of the stored procedures are displayed but with the column description of my first select statement (stored procedure). Is it possible in any way that i could distinguish between the two statements? The reason is because i am using a report page to display information but because i cannot have two datasets in one list, i thought i could combine all the information into one dataset and then distinguish between the information to show in different tables but within the same list/dataset.

Comment: Very confusing. Please consider rephrasing, possibly with code snippets showing your problem areas.

Comment: @HardCode - there really isn't any code yet. I wondering if what i want is even possible. In the report page i can have a list with two tables and each table referring to a different dataset. From trying, a list can only have one dataset. And i don't want to make two lists because that will display the tables in different areas and i want them to be in the same area. I want to know if i create a stored procedure combining two stored procedure(datasets) how can i distinguish what information belongs to which dataset. I will try to create a visual explanation.

Comment: Perhaps you should return one DataTable for the report, and just use the report grouping features. This is usually much, much easier than trying to manipulate multiple DataSets and/or multiple DataTables within a DataSet. I've rewritten ridiculously complex reports, using 5 or 6 DataSets, into one DataSet with report grouping and it was much, much simpler. I could live with the fact that data is repeated in rows, since creation and maintenance was easier.

Comment: @HardCode so you are saying return one dataset with all the information and for my tables i will group the needed info?

Comment: Yes. That is, depending on your data of course. If you can logically query related data into one result set (e.g. Customers and their Orders), you can query customers and all of their orders in one result set. Naturally, the customer info will repeat for each record many times, but use the grouping feature of your reporting tool to display it once.

Comment: @HardCode you've been great help thanks! I will give it a shot and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should return one DataTable for the report, and just use the report grouping features. This is usually much, much easier than trying to manipulate multiple DataSets and/or multiple DataTables within a DataSet. I've rewritten ridiculously complex reports, using 5 or 6 DataSets, into one DataSet with report grouping and it was much, much simpler. I could live with the fact that data is repeated in rows, since creation and maintenance was easier.

That is, depending on your data of course. If you can logically query related data into one result set (e.g. Customers and their Orders), you can query customers and all of their orders in one result set. Naturally, the customer info will repeat for each record many times, but use the grouping feature of your reporting tool to display it once.

Comment: This worked. I just pulled in all the information into one stored procedure and one dataset and depending on the table i filtered the information. What i used is that between the two tables one has an extra column and i checked if the column was null it would work its items in a table and if not null then it was in the other table. My quick question is that is there a way to only show rows with a column i specify if it has a value or not?

Comment: Either add that to your query, or depending on your reporting tool, you can do this. For example, SQL Server Reporting Services has a filter that you can set on the report's DataSet.

Comment: I tried to use the filter which i never used before. This is what i want: CaseId = NULL or Is Nothing. but when running the code I am getting error: cannot compare data of types System.Int32 and System.String. Please check the data type returned by the FilterExpression. How could i do this properly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax - I just know the function is there. I'd suggest starting a new question for that, after searching.